# Nested 'ul' tags showing unexpected output - hidding one part of menu

Tags: html, css, menu

Basically, my idea is to split the menu stubs like 4 on left side & 2 on right side and make it fixed.
accordingly i have written the html & css, but on nesting ul tag inside another ul tag(for right side 2 menu stubs), the menu is getting shorten to those 2 menu stubs(which should be on right side).

here is my HTML & CSS.

Help me.

```css
/* CSS Document */
body {margin: 0;}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
 position: fixed;
   top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 border-right:1px solid white;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #111;}

ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: #4CAF50;}

ul.topnav ul.right {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    ul.topnav ul.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
}color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles\stylo.css">
<title> - </title>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <ul class="topnav right">
 <li><a style="border-left:1px solid white;" href="#">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</ul> 
<div style="padding:20px;margin-top:0px;background-color:#1abc9c;height:1500px;">

<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float` to float each element left and right; both of your `topnav` elements were 100% width, which was why they appeared on top of one another. I've adjusted that and a few other things for the desired effect.

```css
/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-container {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 46px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}
ul.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}
ul.topnav li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
ul.topnav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.topnav.left {
  left: 0;
}
ul.topnav.right {
  right: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul.topnav ul.right,
  ul.topnav li {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles\stylo.css">
  <title>-</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <ul class="topnav left">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
     <ul class="topnav right">
      <li><a style="border-left:1px solid white;" href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="padding:20px;margin-top:0px;background-color:#1abc9c;height:1500px;">

    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```